# Component ID's created from object types passed through template in Entity Component System

Tags: c++, design-patterns, casting

So I've been learning about Entity Component Systems(ECS) and came across this method for creating unique ID's by passing the object as a template parameter. I was wondering how the line:

```
 static ComponentID typeID{getUniqueComponentID()};
```

is creating ID's without having a duplicate ID created again. I know it's probably glaringly obvious.

Here's the entire code that works and doesn't repeat any ID's

```
#include <iostream>

using ComponentID = std::size_t;

//Creates a unique ID for and component that is created
inline ComponentID getUniqueComponentID() noexcept{

    //states that the static ComponentID is going to start at 1
    static ComponentID lastID{1u};
    std::cout<< "Created ID: " << lastID << std::endl;
    return lastID++;

}

//gets the component ID of the Type that is being passed into template
template<typename T>
inline ComponentID getComponentTypeID() noexcept{

    //ComponentID is tied to the templated object type
    static ComponentID typeID{getUniqueComponentID()};
    return typeID;
}

struct A{};
struct B{};
struct C{};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

   std::cout << getComponentTypeID<A>() << std::endl;
   std::cout << getComponentTypeID<B>() << std::endl;
   std::cout << getComponentTypeID<C>() << std::endl;
   std::cout << getComponentTypeID<C>() << std::endl;
   /*
   Output:
   1
   2
   3
   3
   */

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that, in function `getUniqueComponentID()`, `lastID` is declared as `static` and initialized with `1u`. This means that it keeps its values even among several calls to `getUniqueComponentID()`. To finalize, at the end of this function, `lastID` is incremented by 1, so a new value is always return at the end of this function.

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So since typeID is Static as well it gets initialized that one time from what lastID was when a new type was introduced, and it remains that way for all similar types that are passed in after.